# Does awaiting a synchronous function synchronously return a value?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I imported a function from an internal utility library that I am unfamiliar with. There is no documentation for this library and I just assumed it was asynchronous due to its name `getUserDetails`. I thought it was doing an http request.

I used it in an async function like this

```
async function getAllUserInfo(event) {
    const details = await getUserDetails(event);
    // other stuff
}
```

I was wrong in my assumption. A co-worker pointed out that is was not asynchronous. I ended up changing it, but when I was using it incorrectly it still worked. I was able to await a synchronous function and it returned the correct data.

My question is in regards to how it worked.  Does prepending an await on a synchronous function make it resolve on the next tick, or does it return immediately like a synchronous function should?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It worked because `await` does not require its operand to be a promise! It returns the value of the awaited expression if it is not a promise.

See [the documentation for the await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

The important part is:

> ```
> [rv] = await expression;
> ```
>
> - `expression`: A `Promise` or any value to wait for.
> - `rv`: Returns the fulfilled value of the promise, or the value itself if it's not a `Promise`.

In your case `getUserDetails` did not return a promise, but rather some regular user details, so the `await` expression just returned those details, just as if the operator was not there at all.

**However**, even though `getUserDetails` is synchronous, preceding it with `await` in your async function will give up control to its caller, and the "callback portion" after the `await` *is* picked up later. Here is an example script:

```
function f() {
  console.log('In f');
}

async function g() {
  console.log('Starting g');
  await f();
  console.log('Finishing g');
}

console.log('Starting the script')
g();
console.log('Finishing the script')
```

Notice the output of the script:

```
$ node asynctest.js 
Starting the script
Starting g
In f
Finishing the script
Finishing g
```

Notice how the `await` call "paused" g, which was not able to resume until the main block finished! So the `await` *did* have an effect. If you did not put the await there, then you would have seen "Finishing g" before "Finishing the script". Try it out!

BTW the reason for the effect is that even though `await` can be given an expression that does not produce a promise, JS will turn a non-promise operand into a promise immediately resolved to that value. So a promise is still created and the part after await is treated as a callback, which cannot be run until the current execution flow finishes.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing me to the docs. I initially missed the line that said `If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.` So if I understand this correctly, if a synchronous function is prepended with await, it returns the value asynchronously.

Comment: Agreed, very nice. I've elaborated on my answer and included an example which you can run. Hopefully it will clear things up. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll try again.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @RayToal, so is it a bad practice to await any user input which is expected to be a function?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "user input which is expected to be a function"?

Answer (score 8):

If you await a value that is not a promise, it is converted to a resolved promise by using `Promise.resolve`.

```js
function sync(){
 return 1
}

(async ()=>{
  const v = await sync(); console.log(v)
})();

(async ()=>{
  const v = await Promise.resolve(sync()); console.log(v)
})()
```