# This Async Await should not be working. Why is it working then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

So I have been doing React-Native for a couple months now and I stumbled upon a situation where a huge chunk had to be updated in setState function. I had to call a function afterward that was dependent on that state.
Of course the state didn't mutate right away since I learned that setState is Asynchronous.

This is my structure

*Parent*

```
stateSetter = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            ...data
        })
    }
```

```
dateFilter = () => {
        let startDate = this.state.startDate
        let endDate = this.state.endDate
        if (startDate !== "" && endDate == "") {
            this.setState({
                DataFiltered: this.state.Data.filter(elem => Helper.convertDateToISO(elem.date)>= Helper.convertDateToISO(startDate))
            })
        }else if(startDate == "" && endDate !== ""){
            this.setState({
                DataFiltered: this.state.Data.filter(elem => Helper.convertDateToISO(elem.date)<= Helper.convertDateToISO(endDate))
            })
        }else if(startDate !== "" && endDate !== ""){
            this.setState({
                DataFiltered: this.state.Data.filter(elem => Helper.convertDateToISO(elem.date)>= Helper.convertDateToISO(startDate) && Helper.convertDateToISO(elem.date)<= Helper.convertDateToISO(endDate))
            })
        }else if(startDate === "" && endDate === ""){
            this.setState({
                DataFiltered: this.state.Data
            })
        }
    }
```

*Child*

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={async () => {
                await stateSetter({
                    ["startDate"]: "",
                    ["endDate"]: "",
                    ["startDateText"]: "From...",
                    ["endDateText"]: "To..."
                })
                dateFilter()
            }} >
```

Now I was under the belief that Async Await works **only** when await is waiting for a promise.....right?
So by that logic, in the aforementioned code, await and async should have no effect on the program.

**au contraire**

When I don't use async await, it doesn't work. It only works when I use async await.

When I was just learning about async, I tried a couple things and none of them worked.

```
this.setState({ ...data }, () => {
  this.dateFilter()
})
//Had no effect
```

Also: Promise had no effect.

TlDr: Why is my Async Await working?

Comment: _"When I don't use async await, it doesn't work."_ - what doesn't work? I couldn't really understand your problem. BTW, if you use `await` in front of a non-promise value, that is like wrapping that value with `Promise.resolve`: `await 123` -----> `await Promise.resolve(123)`

Comment: I'd have to look at the spec to confirm but I believe that `await` will always somehow postpone the evaluation of the rest of the function to the next tick of the event loop and by that time the state is updated. I'd consider this as bad design however because the code depends on this more or less hidden behavior. Your last example should seems like it should work and would also be the way I recommend.

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't quite understand OP's problem but after reading your comment, I believe OP's asking about why `dateFilter` function sees the updated state when `stateSetter` call is awaited?! If that's so, even with `await`, `dataFilter` function shouldn't see the updated state because state is constant within a particular render.

Comment: @Yousaf: This is a class component. Using `await` will schedule `this.dataFilter()` to be called in the next tick and the state is probably updated in the next microtick, i.e. before `dataFilter` is called.

Comment: @FelixKling ah, right. Completely missed the use of `this.setState`.

Comment: @Yousaf that makes sense that await wraps the function in a promise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Because you are using `await`, the rest of the function is scheduled to be executed in the future and at that point in time the state will have been updated. Whether or not you are actually `await`ing a promise is irrelevant.

---

I don't know the internals of React, but I assume the queue a [*micro task*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide) to update the state. Promise callbacks are also processed as a micro task (and `async/await` is just a nice way to work with promises).

So first React adds a micro task to update the state, and then `await` adds a micro task for resuming the function.

We can actually do a simple experiment to verify what the order of events is by passing a callback to `setState` (no JSX because somehow I couldn't make it a working snippet):

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  async doStuff() {
    await this.setState({newState: true}, () => console.log('inside setState callback', JSON.stringify(this.state)));
    console.log('after await this.setState', JSON.stringify(this.state));
  }
  
  render() {
    return React.createElement('button', {onClick: () => this.doStuff()}, 'Click me');
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Component),
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you run this you will see that the callback gets called first. We know that the state has been updated at this point because that's the whole purpose of the callback: It is executed when the state has been updated.

Then the remainder of the function is executed, and since the state has already been updated, it will be accessing the new state.

However, since you are were wondering yourself why this works, I would recommend against this practice and just use the `setState` callback.

Answer (score 0):

1. await ins your sample won't work as expected as stateSetter not returning an promise

To make await applicable for stateSetter it must return an Promise

```
stateSetter = (data) => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
}
```

2. Checkout this pretty good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113281/does-awaiting-a-synchronous-function-synchronously-return-a-value) about what's going on here

Comment: *"won't work as expected"* But the OP is saying exactly that. And the answer you linked to confirms that using `await`, with or without promise, will delay the execution of the remainder of the function.