# How to work with a function that can be either sync or async

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `doSomething` which is created dynamically and can be either sync or async.

I can just await it anyways

```
const a = await doSomething()
```

Since if it's sync, the await would just have no meaning, but is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, just always consider it to be asynchronous, it should do no harm.

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: What do you mean by better? Using the await keyword for both sync and async functions is ok. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113281/does-awaiting-a-synchronous-function-synchronously-return-a-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since if it's sync, the await would just have no meaning...

Not *quite*, it would still make the following code wait until the microtask queue was processed, rather than being synchronous.

Unless there's a major problem with that, though, just do that and don't worry about it. *(More on that below.)*

> but is there a better way?

If possible, avoid this kind of ambiguity in the first place.

If you can't, though, and you really want to make the code synchronous if `doSomething` didn't return a promise, you can check whether the function returned a *thenable* (such as a promise, which is what an `async` function returns):

```
const t = doSomething();
const a = typeof t?.then === "function" ? await t : t;
```

That keeps the code synchronous if `doSomething` didn't return a thenable, but makes it asynchronous if it did.

Again, though, I'd avoid this if at all possible, by avoiding the ambiguity or just using `await` regardless.

---

A side note: I really would suggest just using `await`. That way, regardless of what `doSomething` returns, you **know** your code runs with that async behavior. If you use the workaround above, it's chaotic, you don't know whether your code is going to be synchronous or asynchronous. Chaos isn't your friend when reasoning about what your code is doing. :-)